# Efficient string matching in java

Tags: java, regex, string, string-matching

I have a stream of sentences (tweets) and over 10 million names. I want to determine if a single sentence (tweet) contains mention of one of the 10 million names. I could compile regex for all the possible patterns but I would really like to know if there is an efficient algorithm to do that.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean: ten million regexes, or one regex with all all ten million names joined together into an alternation?  Either way, it sounds like more fun than a human should be allowed. ;)  But seriously, this is not a job for regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build [a trie (a prefix tree)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 3):

You might try using [Bloom filter](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained). [Demo here](http://billmill.org/bloomfilter-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. Bloom fliter might help. I will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need pattern matching at all, if you only seek for the occurence of a simple string (name). If you are actually aiming at twitter names -- are they not prefixed with an @ sign when mentioned in tweets? If so, at first just seek for the @ sign and proceed from there.

To check if the string after the @ is one of your 10 million strings, a prefix tree as proposed by ruakh is definitely a good idea
.

Comment: Thanks. It is not always the case that they are prefixed with an @. Some brand names are not.

Answer (score 0):

You could go about it from the other way round.  As the sentence comes in, split it into tokens and build a RegEx Pattern for each token, something like ^*token*\s*. Compare each of those against your 10 million names assuming each on line.

Comment: Thanks but this involve chunking the sentence to detect nouns which is pretty expensive to do given millions of sentences. I hope I understood your suggestion correctly.